# Handling Http Calls in Https Site

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, http, https

I am having `Http` reference in my `html` [referring `Java script` files hosted by google] and i have a `Https` site so when the page loads it shows "Only secured content is displayed".

I need to make this call Https instead of http. I trued accessing http request in Application_BeginRequest method but it turn out to be, Request object is read only.

Please suggest any method

Answer (score 1):

This is a security measure of the browser.

Check whether you can get the script when changing http to https - sometimes google js files are accessible via https also.

The only other possibility - which additionally helps to circumvent cross-site scripting problems - is to have the server fetch the file from google via http, and serve it via https to its own application.

Comment: if you place a link like <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
the appropriate protocol will be chosen, if available.
I had a problem that was similar, only in this case a faulty Github SSL cert prevented the script from downloading. I also just fetched the script and included it locally.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the reference to https. Google offers all of their links with http and https addresses. You can change the request to https from the source code, there is no need to dynamically change it in Application_BeginRequest.

If you really had to do it in the Application_BeginRequest phase you could use this code:

```
Sub Application_BeginRequest(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    ' Fires at the beginning of each request
    If Not Request.IsSecureConnection Then
        Dim path As String = String.Format("https{0}", Request.Url.AbsoluteUri.Substring(4))
        Response.Redirect(path)
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: @ Craig Moore : i have http referred in entire solution not enough time to manually change all references. can you help in changing it in Application_BeginRequest

Comment: Responce.Redirect is giving error. i also think you need to do some thing with request object not Responce

Comment: What is the error and what does `path` equal when it tries to do the redirect? You do not need to alter the request object as the response is being directed, at most you can end the response early if you like.